# MongoDB too many authentication log messages

Tags: mongodb, authentication, logging

my log keeps appending this message

```
authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
```

I do not understand what it means and is it possible to not show it? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is evidently no way to quiet down this inter-server logging, since it is the subject of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5847 which recently turned 2 years old.